# encryption/decryption program C++

Tags: c++, encryption, codeblocks

My homework is making an encrypting/decrypting program where the user enters the message and a key that has the same number of letters. 
The program encrypts the message and shows it then decrypts the cipher and shows the message again.
i have a problem decrypting the cipher, when i write HELLO and the key is JHBZA it shows HELPO instead of HELLO. what's the problem in the code?

```
       #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char message[100], key[100], encryption[100], decryption[100];
    int msgvalue [100], msgvalue2 [100], keyvalue [100], keyvalue2 [100], sum[100], decryptvalue[100], decryptvalue2[100];
    int i=0;

cout << "Enter the message: ";
cin.getline(message, 100);
while(message[i] != '\0')
{

    msgvalue[i] = message[i];
    msgvalue2[i] = msgvalue[i] - 65;
    i++;
}

i=0;

cout << "Enter the key: ";
cin.getline(key, 100);
while(key[i] != '\0')
{
    keyvalue[i] = key[i];
    keyvalue2[i] = keyvalue[i] -65;
    i++;
}



cout << "The message is: " << setw(15) << message << endl;
for(int i = 0; msgvalue[i] > 1; i++)
{
sum [i] = msgvalue2[i] + keyvalue2[i];
sum[i] = sum[i] % 26;
}



cout << "The cipher is: " << setw(12);

for(int i = 0; msgvalue[i] >= 65 && msgvalue[i] <= 90; i++)
{
 encryption[i] = sum[i] + 65;

 cout << encryption[i];
}


cout << endl << "The message again is: " << setw(12);

for(int i = 0; msgvalue[i] >= 65 && msgvalue[i] <= 90; i++)
{
decryptvalue[i] =(sum[i] - keyvalue2[i]) % 26;

if (decryptvalue[i] < 0)
{
    decryptvalue[i] = -decryptvalue[i] ;
}


decryptvalue2[i]  = decryptvalue[i] + 65;

decryption[i] = decryptvalue2[i];

cout << decryption[i];

}


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is with all of the back slashes?

Comment: no idea but i fixed it sorry!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @nathanoliver thank you i will look through that! for now i know the problem is this equation

Comment: decryptvalue[i] =(sum[i] - keyvalue2[i]) % 26;

it doesn't work for keys starting from s to z when i write H as the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Z' = 25
'L' = 11

Therefore (25 + 11) % 26 = 10

When you go to decrypt it, (10 - 25) % 26 = -15

You then take the absolute value for this, setting it to 15. Instead, the correct thing to do when the decrypted value is < 0 is add 26. Which would turn -15 into 11. 11 = 'L'.